# app.module not generated my AngularCLI

Tags: angular, module, angular-cli

I've just embarked on my new journey to learn `Angular2`, I've brought a course via udemy.  Everything is going well however I've noticed due to the latest release of `Angular2` projects are now using a file called `app.module`.

When I create my new project via `AngularCLI` is doesn't seem to create the `app.module`? Instead it creates the project via the old way without using the `app.module` I've searched the web assuming it may have something to do with the version of `AngularCLI` I'm using however nothing has come up on my search confirming this.

Which now brings me to stackoverflow to ask the question: Do I need to upgrade `AngularCLI` for it to generate the `app.module` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of angular-cli are you using?

NgModules were implemented in Angular 2 RC6, not a long time ago, so in short:

yes, you should upgrade to the newest version of angular-cli to have access to all the latest features.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, can you tell me how I check what version Angular-cli I have?

Comment: Managed to find it I'm using the following angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 4.4.7

Comment: I'm trying to find out how I can upgrade my version of angular-cli but I can't find anything online, do you know how to?

Comment: yes, you need to do `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`, `npm cache clean`, and finally `npm install -g angular-cli`